# Word for describing something by a characteristic that's plainly obvious?

Tags: word-choice

I'm wondering if there's a definition for phrases like:

- The Green apple is Green
- Some optional options are optional
- Silly people are Silly
- We visited the museum, where we saw museum artefacts.

Where a description of something is otherwise worthless or repeated.

Googling hasn't helped much, so time to ask real people!

Comment: Are you looking for ***tautology***?   They’re all *tautological*.

Comment: As well as tautology may like to look up redundancy , pleonasm, and reiteration in your  dictionary.

Comment: Aphorism is often used when a slightly negative connotation is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with "**tautology**". That is the word used, and concept established, in **formal logic**, which is a discipline in mathematical science.

Others already mentioned **pleonasm** and **aphorism**. These are used more often in the **literary sense**, or in **argumentation and interpretation of persuasive appeals**.

However, the overly verbose quality of your examples reminds me of archaic or out-of-practice words like

Perissology

> superfluity of words [archaic] (Merriam)

Supererogatory

> observed or performed to an extent not enjoined or required (Merriam)